# How to pass the asp.net dropdown selected item as an input to a stored procedure in c#?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

This is the code i am using.. I want to pass the dropdown selected item as a input to the stored procedure and execute that.. how could i achieve that?

```
public class DaysForEvents
{
    public DataSet GetDaysForEvents(//This should be my input to stored procedure (i.e)  dropdownselected value)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CommonSettings.GetEventsConnectionString());

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("proc_fetch_event_days", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           //DateFilter = 0;
            //StatusFilter = 0;

            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_id", Event_id);
            // sqlcmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = UserID;


            con.Open();
            sqlda.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();

            return ds;


        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make too much sense here. Where is your dropdown item? And Where is `UserID` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want this.

```
//get dropdown selected value and store in a variable 
var eventId = dropdown.SelectedValue; 

//pass this variable in the GetDaysForEvents method to get DataSet.
var dataSet = GetDaysForEvents(eventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_id", yourDropDown.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function like

```
string eventId = ddlEvents.SelectedValue;
GetDaysForEvents(eventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

-User `using` statement to close your connection and dispose your unused resources.

-The `DataAdapter` open the connection by itself, so no need of `Open()`;

```
public DataSet GetDaysForEvents(string eventId)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", connection){ CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventId", eventId);
            using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

And somewhere else

```
var events = yourClassInstance.GetDaysForEvents(dropDown.SelectedValue);
```